# Replace a string from a list with the next line from another list

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

I have 3 files. One is a list of foods and categories:

```
                 food="rice"
                 product="cereal"
                 food="beans"
                 product="bean"
                 food="cake"
                 product="bakery"
                 food="lettuce"
                 product="leaves"
```

The second is a list of only of the foods:

```
                 food="rice"
                 food="beans"
                 food="cake"
                 food="lettuce"
```

On the third file I have lines that contain strings of /food file (e.g. /food="rice") and I need to replace these strings by the corresponding product listed on the first file. To simplify: find the string from file 2 on file 3 and replace by the next line of file one on file 3. 
I thought maybe a combination of grep and sed but I can't figure out how to... 
 The third file looks something like this

```
>[food="rice"] [some other sutff] [calories=398]
Here is a recipe with rice
>[food="beans"] [some other sutff] [calories=250]
Here is a recipe with beans
>[food="cake"] [some other sutff] [calories=100]
Here is a recipe for cake
>[food="lettuce"] [some other sutff] [calories=02]
Why would you need a recipe for lettuce?
```

And I need it to look like...

```
 >[product="cereal"] [some other sutff] [calories=398]
 Here is a recipe with rice
 >[product="bean"] [some other sutff] [calories=250]
 Here is a recipe with beans
 >[product="bakery" [some other sutff] [calories=100]
 Here is a recipe for cake
 >[product="leaves"] [some other sutff] [calories=02]
 Why would you need a recipe for lettuce?
```

Comment: Could you please post 3rd file's sample too along with expected output sample and let us know then?

Comment: I just updated the post

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Comment: @SilviaJusti, still not clear, please elaborate more on it?

Comment: Why do you need the second file with foods only?

Comment: I wouldn't. It could find the food replace by the corresponding product. That is how stuck I am today...

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `sed`:

```
sed -f <(sed 'N;s/\n/\//;s/^/s\//;s/$/\//' one) three
```

If every line of the first file really starts with whitespace, that becomes

```
sed -f <(sed 'N;s/ *//g;s/\n/\//;s/^/s\//;s/$/\//' one ) three
```

Comment: Thank you very much for correcting my mistake. I have amended my answer.

Answer (score 0):

here is a `sed/awk` combination

```
$ sed -f <(awk '     {gsub(/ /,"")} 
             NR==FNR {if(/food/) k=$0; if(/product/) a[k]=$0; next} 
             $0 in a {print "s/" $0 "/" a[$0] "/g"}' f1 f2) f3

>[product="cereal"] [some other sutff] [calories=398]
Here is a recipe with rice
>[product="bean"] [some other sutff] [calories=250]
Here is a recipe with beans
>[product="bakery"] [some other sutff] [calories=100]
Here is a recipe for cake
>[product="leaves"] [some other sutff] [calories=02]
Why would you need a recipe for lettuce?
```

Comment: Almost, I only want the >[food="rice"] to change to >[food="cereal"], the next line should be kept intact, and still say rice... It needs to be an exact match, not just to the category, but to the rest of the string too

Comment: fixed, as long as there is no white space it should work, otherwise you need to trim them from the tokens.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see what file2 would be used for.

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[][]" }
NR==FNR {
    gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"")
    if (NR%2) { food = $0 }
    else { map[food] = $0 }
    next
}
{
    sub(/\[[^][]+/,"["map[$2])
    print
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file3
>[product="cereal"] [some other sutff] [calories=398]
Here is a recipe with rice
>[product="bean"] [some other sutff] [calories=250]
Here is a recipe with beans
>[product="bakery"] [some other sutff] [calories=100]
Here is a recipe for cake
>[product="leaves"] [some other sutff] [calories=02]
Why would you need a recipe for lettuce?
```